# Angular app using OAuth2 Code Flow with PKCE ( ADFS ) code validation error

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, adfs, adfs4.0

I'm trying to implement `code flow with pkce` in an Angular client, having ADFS 2019. I'm currently getting the error `Unable to validate code_verifier`.

I'm generating the `code_verifier` and `code_challenge` using the following algorithm:

---

`code_verifier = base64UrlEncode(randomString(length))`
where `length=45` 
`code_challenge = base64UrlEncode(sha256(code_verifier))`

I've checked the `code_verifier` that I'm sending along with the `code` that I receive from ADFS and it matches the one generated when constructing the login url.

Is there something wrong with my implementation?

Edit: Could I somhow debug ADFS and see the string it receives and the string it compares it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it working by making the following changes:

```
 - Skipped encoding the code_verifier
 - Changed the hashing steps for the code_challenge. 
I was turning the ArrayBuffer into an Array, the Array into a string and base64UrlEncode the string.
What I changed here was that I directly encoded the ArrayBuffer and skipped the conversions.
```

I used a lib to bring all this functionality to JS https://www.npmjs.com/package/@waiting/base64/v/4.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can look at the event log in ADFS and see if any errors are recorded.

There is no way to "step-through" ADFS.

The C# code sample [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce-in-adfs-for-windows-server-2019-a457172e28c3) works and may guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought - but the excellent oidc client library might be able to deal with this for you.

One option might be to repoint my standards based SPA sample (coded in an easy to debug plain procedural manner) to your ADFS base url:
https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/

This should just involve an update to the OAuth settings in the config file:
https://github.com/gary-archer/authguidance.websample1/blob/master/spa/spa.config.json

Not sure if it helps - but I know the PKCE handling in my SPA is 100% correct and it will give you something to compare against